# Lexicographic order Word

Tags: combinatorics

A contestant must figure out a hidden word that can be formed from the letters AAAPPLLMN I He is indicated that the word has the form PA_ _A_I _ L _. It is indicated that considering only the letters that remain to be placed, none of them are in the lexicographic order (written from left to right). How many words would he have to make now?

Un concursante debe averiguar una palabra oculta que puede formarse con las
letras AAAPPLLMN I
Le indican que la palabra tiene la forma PA_ _A_I _ L  _.
Le dicen que considerando solo las letras que quedan por colocar ninguna de ellas está en el orden lexicográfico (escritas de izquierda a derecha). ¿Cuántas palabras tendría que formar ahora?

Comment: lexcographic order is just the order used in a dictionary (alphabetically), so A < AA < AB < AC< BA etc.

Comment: Ok. What does it mean for the 5 letters A P L M N to not be in lexicographic order?

Comment: Well L should be before P. Your question is very unclear. Please state it literally (even in Spanish is OK)

Comment: But you cant know that. They don't give me the 5 missing letters In a particular order.

Comment: Still a rather obscure question, IMO. A letter by itself is not in "orden lexicográfico" but only in relation the other letters and it's not clear to me whether the asker wants to consider the order within the whole word or not, for me the lexicographic order is between words, not just letters.

Comment: If the remaining letters are in reverse lexicographic among themselves then there is but one way to complete the word, obviously. But that seems to me a weird interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ver cuántas combinaciones puedes hacer

Si fuera ABC. Las opciones son

ABC, ACB,
BAC, BCA,
CAB, CBA.

3*2*1

Pero la primera no puede ser A, la segunda no puede ser B y la tercera no puede ser C. So te queda. BCA y CAB

DABC, DACB, DBAC, DBCA, DCAB, DCBA.
ADBC, ADCB, ABDC, ABCD, ACDB, ACBD.
BADC, BACD, BDAC, BDCA, BCAD, BCDA.
CABD, CADB, CBAD, CBDA, CDAB, CDBA.

4*3*2*1

DABC, DCAB, DCBA.
BADC, BDAC, BCDA.
CADB, CDAB, CDBA.

Te quedan 5 letras pa escojer. Si vas a tener 120 pero pierdes una fila y la mitad de las columnas. (120×4/5)/2 = 48.